# How to to implement a forgot password feature using the Google Identity Toolkit in php

Tags: php

I am trying to add google identity toolkit in php. Signin option is working correctly but when i am clicking on problem in sign in link it is showing capthca after submitting captcha it is not navigating to any url.
*email.php*

```
<?php
include "identity-toolkit-php-client-master/src/GitkitClient.php";
$gitkitClient=new Gitkit_Client();
$oob_response = $gitkitClient->getOobResults($_POST);
$oob_link = $oob_response['oobLink'];
echo json_encode($oob_response);

?>
```

email.php is the oobactionurl file. when i am using this code I am getting this error .[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z07UE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a php file to retrieve and send the reset link to the user. Make sure the `oobActionUrl` widget option points to this file. Within the file, you'll get the generated link and additional information by calling `$gitkitClient->getOobResults($_POST)`. It should also work if you exclude $_POST, as the function will check the post contents if no arguments are passed. Then, you can get the link itself like this:
`$oob_response = $gitkitClient->getOobResults($_POST);
$oob_link = $oob_response['oobLink'];`

From there, you can use your email function of choice to send it to the user.  The returned array should contain the following.

'email' => email of the user,
'oldEmail' => old email (for ChangeEmail only),
'newEmail' => new email (for ChangeEmail only),
'oobLink' => url for user click to finish the operation,
'action' => 'RESET_PASSWORD', or 'CHANGE_EMAIL',
'response_body' => http response to be sent back to Gitkit widget

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Hi Morley , to call $gitkitClient->getOobResults($_POST) I have downloaded library files from this  [link](https://github.com/google/identity-toolkit-php-client) and I unzipped the files, but I don,t know where to keep these files. whether I need to keep in /gitkit folder or any other folder?

Comment: I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/required-endpoints#handling_forgotten_passwords) document. I didn't understand. If you know know the flow just explain me.

Comment: It's up to you where you want to keep the Gitkit php files. Just make sure to include them when running your code.

Comment: The directions in the page you linked only apply if you're not using one of the official Google libraries.

Comment: Hi, I have followed your steps(code and error mentioned above),But still I am getting error. Thanks

Comment: You need to also include the OAuth2.php file. Here's the repository: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/. The file path is /src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php. That's probably the issue with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160433/google-identity-toolkit-login-is-not-working-for-php) as well, which I'll update shortly.

Comment: This repository github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master showing 404.

Comment: Oops, try this link: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master.