# google identity toolkit login is not working for php

Tags: php, toolkit

I have followed this document [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/php) to create login in php using google identity toolkit. when I am using below mentioned code index page showing as blank. In browser console it is showing error like (500 internal server error). index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- 1: Load the Google Identity Toolkit helpers -->
<?php
  set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . __DIR__ .'/vendor/google/apiclient/src');
  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $gitkitClient = Gitkit_Client::createFromFile(dirname(__FILE__) . '/gitkit-server-config.json');
  $gitkitUser = $gitkitClient->getUserInRequest();
?>
<!-- End modification 1 -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<link type=text/css rel=stylesheet href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />

<script type=text/javascript>
  window.google.identitytoolkit.signInButton(
    '#navbar',
    {
      widgetUrl: "/gitkit",
      signOutUrl: "/index"
    }
  );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar"></div>

<!-- 2: Print the user information if a signed in user is present -->
<p>
  <?php if ($gitkitUser) { ?>
    Welcome back!<br><br>
    Email: <?= $gitkitUser->getEmail() ?><br>
    Id: <?= $gitkitUser->getUserId() ?><br>
    Name: <?= $gitkitUser->getDisplayName() ?><br>
    Identity provider: <?= $gitkitUser->getProviderId() ?><br>
  <?php } else { ?>
    You are not logged in yet.
  <?php } ?>
</p>
<!-- End modification 2 -->

</body>
</html>
```

gitkit.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- Copy and paste here the client configuration from Developer Console into the config variable -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/js/gitkit.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//www.gstatic.com/authtoolkit/css/gitkit.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var config =
    // Copy and paste client configuration here
  ;
  // The HTTP POST body should be escaped by the server to prevent XSS
  window.google.identitytoolkit.start(
      '#gitkitWidgetDiv', // accepts any CSS selector
      config,
      JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input")); ?>')
  );
</script>
<!-- End modification -->

</head>
<body>

<!-- Include the sign in page widget with the matching 'gitkitWidgetDiv' id -->
<div id="gitkitWidgetDiv"></div>
<!-- End identity toolkit widget -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, you need to include OAuth2.php as well. Here's the repository: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master. The file path is /src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php. Let me know if that fixes the problem.